# returning reference to a vector from a method and using its public members

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a vector `t_vec` that stores references to instances of class `Too`. The code is shown below. In the `main` , I have a vector t_vec_2 which has the same memory address as `B::t_vec`.

But when I try to access t_vec_2[0].val1 it gives error `val1 not declared`.

Could you please point out what is wrong? Also, if you know of a better way to return a vector from a method, please let me know! Thanks in advance.

```
class Too {      
      public:             
             Too();
             ~Too(){};
          int val1;
};

Too::Too(){
           val1 = 10;
           };


class B {
      public:
             vector<Too*> t_vec;
             Too*  t1;
             vector<Too*>& get_tvec();
             B(){t1 = new Too();};
             ~B(){delete t1;};
};

vector<Too*>& B::get_tvec(){
    t_vec.push_back(t1);
    return t_vec;
}

int main(){
    B b;
    b = B();
    vector<Too*>& t_vec_2 = b.get_tvec();

    // Getting error    
    std::cout << "\n val1 = " << t_vec_2[0].val1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 errors:
The first was already said, you should write

```
t_vec_2[0]->val1
```

instead of

```
t_vec_2[0].val1
```

The second is the strange line
b = B();

I think you should delete it.
The error occurs because right part B() is gonna be delete just after it is created.
So you don't get in the object b the 10 value as you want. Just delete this line and it'll be ok!

Comment: While I agree the second line is strange, that should not affect the output of the program itself.

Comment: when you write b = B() the following occures:
Suppose that at the right part there is created temporary object b_2
Then there is operator = which is embedded in c++ (but you can redefine it! than it will work normally). The operator = makes b.t1 = b_2.t1. But just after that, b_2 is dying, so your pointer b_2.t1 is deleted, and b.t1 is also becomes bad pointer.

Comment: oops!  Thank you very much guys, That resolved the issue! Also, if you have any comments on returning the vector itself (e.g. any better design you can think of ) please let me know!

Comment: Oops. +1 (afdasfdasdfafd character limit)

Answer (score 1):

> But when I try to access t_vec_2[0].val1 it gives error val1 not declared.

That's because your vector is holding pointers, not `Too` objects. Replace the dot (`.`) operator with the arrow (`->`) operator, like this:

```
std::cout << "\n val1 = " << t_vec_2[0]->val1;
```

As a general rule though, you should probably avoid having public members at all.

Comment: thanks billy. I tried using arrow operator. The code compiles, but val1 prints some garbage value (should print 10 instead) 

About avoiding public members: Do you mean making t_vec private and ony returning its members to outside classes by get* methods?.. if so, will do so, but still interested in how to resolve this issue... thanks again